# Need to convert and add 3 months in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
1st May, 2006
3rd June,2008
22nd December, 2010
```

I need this to be converted to date format and add 3 months

Comment: What have you tried yourself?

Comment: Please edit the title so you are not shouting at us.

Answer (score 1):

one can use EDATE and SUBSTITUTE and REPLACE:

```
=EDATE(--SUBSTITUTE(REPLACE(A1,MIN(FIND({"st","nd","rd","th"},A1&"stndrdth")),2,""),",",""),3)
```

I think I have all the suffixes, but if needed add the suffix to both the search array and the added string.

Depending on one's version this may require the use of Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Comment: And as I said in my answer, this one is indeed cleaner!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure there is a cleaner way of doing this:

```
=DATE(RIGHT(A2;4);MATCH(MID(A2;SEARCH(" ";A2)+1;(SEARCH(",";A2)-1)-(SEARCH(" ";A2)+1)+1);{"January";"February";"March";"April";"May";"June";"July";"August";"September";"October";"November";"December"};0);SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A2;(SEARCH(" ";A2)+1)-2);"st";"");"nd";"");"rd";"");"th";""))
```

[image]

To add 3 months, is same formula inside EDATE:

```
=EDATE(DATE(RIGHT(A2;4);MATCH(MID(A2;SEARCH(" ";A2)+1;(SEARCH(",";A2)-1)-(SEARCH(" ";A2)+1)+1);{"January";"February";"March";"April";"May";"June";"July";"August";"September";"October";"November";"December"};0);SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A2;(SEARCH(" ";A2)+1)-2);"st";"");"nd";"");"rd";"");"th";""));3)
```

[image]